# Как в Андроид Студио сделать так, чтобы приложение в заданных странах запускалось на русском языке? Т.е. чтобы values-ru использовался для них

Tags: android-studio

Как в **Андроид Студио** сделать так, чтобы приложение в заданных странах  запускалось на русском языке (сейчас запускается на Английском)? Т.е., чтобы ресурс **values-ru** использовался в телефоне (устройстве), если в нем настроен например, Украинский язык.

Я знаю, что в папку **values-uk** можно скопировать содержимое из папки **values-ru** и это работает. Но это же не серьезное решение. ) Нужно решать через какие-то настройки (ссылки)...

По умолчанию в приложении, как Вы понимаете, настроен Английский язык.

Comment: просто сделайте правильный перевод. Всего то делов.